# WordPress : using AJAX to get posts & Sidebar Content to an external application

Tags: customization, posts, ajax

Hello friends I am trying to get my wordpress posts to display in a non- wordpress application. Currently I am getting them by using the following method.

My wordPress page is something like this:

```
<div id="header">
    <!-- header content goes here -->
</div>

<div id="main-body">

    <div id="content">
        <!-- Main Body goes here -->
    </div>

    <div id="sidebar">
        <!-- My Sidebar Widgets go here -->
    </div>
</div>

<div id="footer"
    <!-- My footer goes here -->
</div>
```

and I am using:

```
<?php file_get_contents('http://mysite.com/blog'); ?>
```

It's working ok but there are 2 issues.........

1. It is getting the entire page.
2. My page stops loading till it fetches the wordpress data.

Hence I thought AJAX was the solution. But I don't know AJAX. hence decided to seek help here.

What I am looking for is that I just want the output content of #Content Div and #sidebar Div separately so that I can place them in my other application in two different places.

I don't even need the CSS or JS as they are common for both my themes. I just want the output and separately placed at 2 different place.

Please help.

Comment: You could do a JSON request using MooTools(you mentioned using it in one of your comments).. http://mootools.net/docs/core/Request/Request.JSON ... not used Moo Tools myself, but the page linked provides a simple enough example(let me know if it helps).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is all on same server it is rather easy to load WP engine and parts you need, see [Integrating WordPress with Your Website](http://codex.wordpress.org/Integrating_WordPress_with_Your_Website).

Otherwise there is probably better to get specific data (rather than whole page) from WordPress remotely, but there are a lot of approaches to that. Also I am not aware of any off-the-shelf code that allows to do that for sidebars. For post content there is [XML-RPC](http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_Support) support and plugins for other formats (I think I read about JSON one).

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery, you can request part of a page. [Here's an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2137811/extract-part-of-html-document-in-jquery) using this technique.

Comment: Actually I am using MooTools in my other application an I dont want to load another library like jQuery just for this purpose as it will make my application heavy